# How would one go about replaying transactions on Ethereum chains?

Tags: go-ethereum, replay-attack, geth-debugging

**Ignoring** [EIP 155](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-155.md) and any other measures in place to prevent this, how would one technically replay a transaction on some other Ethereum chain?

Context: I have two private chains and want to see if I can replicate Chain 1's state by taking all txns and replaying them on a fresh Chain 2.

I thought I'd be able to resumbit `input` from `web3.eth.getTransaction()` in `web3.eth.sendRawTransaction()` but am getting an undocumented `rlp` error (`expected input list for types.txdata`), which seems to indicate the node is unhappy about something fundamental in the encoding process. The transaction I'm trying with is a contract deployment.

Keep in mind that we're replaying right from the start, so nonces should not be an issue. All relevant accounts are funded.

Geth: `1.7.2-stable`

Web3: `0.17.0-beta`

Comment: `input` is probably the wrong thing to submit as e.g. value txns only have `0x`, so that doesn't make sense.